# ag-grid Master / Detaile expanded row not Re-adjustment height

Tags: ag-grid

ag-grid (angular) Master / Detail  expanded row not  Re-adjustment  according to the content height.

[image]
How can i resolved that problem.

i want to implement like given below link. 
https://demos.devexpress.com/aspxgridviewdemos/masterdetail/MasterDetail.aspx